# How to create custom document _id in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

This is sample logstash output filter.

```
output
{
    elasticsearch
    {
            hosts => ["localhost"]
            sniffing => true
            manage_template => false
            index => "mqtt-index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            document_id => "%{parsedMessage.device_id}"
            document_type => "iot_data"
    }
}
```

This code changes existing _id as %{parsedMessage.device_id} as it is. How  to change _id by another field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed the target option from filter.

`filter
{
        json
        {
                source => "message"
        }
}`

And use following output for creating custom document id.

```
output
{
    elasticsearch
    {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            sniffing => true
            manage_template => false
            index => "mqtt-index-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            document_id => "%{device_id}"
            document_type => "iot_data"
    }
}
```

Comment: ya i removed the target from json filter now its working

Answer (score 0):

The notation is not correct you need to do it this way

```
        document_id => "%{[parsedMessage][device_id]}"
```

Comment: Can you show an event? Add this in your output section: `stdout{codec=>rubydebug}`

Comment: Thank you. But this is not nested field the field name itself is parsedMessage.device_id

Comment: Ah! That's not a good idea to have dots inside field names :-)

Comment: actually message = {"value": 27.6, "datastream_name": "pressure", "context": {"latitude": 19.4, "elevation": 35.9, "longitude": 11.1}, "device_id": 9} this is my message filed and from this field i have separated all the fields thats y the new fields created are parsedMessage.device.id , parsedMessage.value like that

Comment: Please show what you get from the `stdout` output (update your question with it)

Comment: Care to share more?